# Calculate duration of time events

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have dataframes that have the following structure:

| ID | Time | Entry | Hit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 989 | 2021-04-22 06:07:12 | 2 | 0 |
| 989 | 2021-04-24 09:35:12 | 4 | 1 |
| 989 | 2021-04-24 19:35:12 | 6 | 1 |
| 989 | 2021-04-25 09:35:12 | 8 | 1 |
| 989 | 2021-04-25 12:35:12 | 3 | 0 |
| 989 | 2021-04-25 23:35:12 | 1 | 0 |
| 989 | 2021-04-24 09:35:12 | 4 | 1 |
| 989 | 2021-04-24 09:35:12 | 7 | 1 |
| 989 | 2021-04-24 09:35:12 | 5 | 1 |

What I want to achieve is to calculate the duration of each episode, the longest episode, as well as the number of episodes and their mean and median which are marked with a 1.

At the end I want to get a DF more less like that:

| ID | No_Epsiode | maxlen | duration_ep_x | Median_ep_x | Mean_ep_x | duration_ep_y | Median_ep_y | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 989 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 990 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 991 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

I am currently stuck because I lack the experience with pandas to build this loop.

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Which field represents the episode? What do the entry and hit fields mean?

Comment: The hit flied represents the episode, entry it's just scoring point system. From where i want to calculate the median and variance if it's and episode (hits=1)

Comment: But what is an episode? is it just all the hits that happen in one timestamp, so you'd have 3 episodes (4 hits at 2021-04-24 09:35:12, 1 hit at 2021-04-24 19:35:12, 1 hit at 2021-04-25 09:35:12)?

Comment: An episode start is when hits has his first 1 in this example  it has the timestampe 2021-04-24 09:35:12 and ends with the timestamp 2021-04-25 09:35:12. The ones are acutally only indicating that there is an episode. In this example df, I have 2 episodes with 3 entries, in which I want to know the duration, median and mean of the value during this episode.
Hopefully it could be explained understandably now

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.